# Codename One and Java synchronized keyword

Tags: codenameone

I had a suspect that a bug in one of my Codename One projects was caused by concurrent executions of the same listener *(if the user taps a button very quickly more times, invoking its listener before it ended the execution)*... I added a lock variable in the code, to avoid multiple executions at the same time, and this solved the bug.

This is my first time that I have this kind of problem. Reading on the web, it's suggested to use the `synchronized` Java keyword (however I'm not sure if it can be useful in this case).

My question is if the `synchronized` Java keyword is supported by Codename One.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`synchronized` works fine in Codename One but if you used an action listener it's unlikely that it solved the issue unless we have a **huge** unimaginable bug.

All events, paints, lifecycle methods etc. are invoked on the EDT. It's a single thread so two clicks on the button will happen on a single thread. `synchronized` would be meaningless. The EDT is used from the touch screen interaction all the way down to the event on the component itself and you can test that through the `isEDT()` method.

A more likely scenario is that one of the action listeners on the button uses `invokeAndBlock` which can trigger weird side effects in the event dispatch chain. `invokeAndBlock()` is used internally by `AndWait` methods, dialogs etc.

Comment: Thank you very much for the interesting and clarifying answer. I was confused because I thought that the execution of the ActionListener was in a separate thread. Maybe I found the true cause of the bug: the use of `animateUnlayout` (that returns immediately, allowing another execution of the same listener to start without waiting the end of the animation) instead of `animateUnlayoutAndWait` (that prevents another listener execution before the animation ends). In the case of `animateUnlayout`, the animation is executed inside or outside the EDT? I'm asking that because it returns immediatly.

Comment: Both animations execute 100% on the EDT. The animation just turns on a "flag" that causes the animation to run for every EDT loop (AKA tick). The `AndWait` method uses `invokeAndBlock` to open a thread that only waits (doesn't do anything else). `invokeAndBlock` takes the EDT and keeps it running but the lines immediately after don't occur because they are already in the middle of execution. So once `invokeAndBlock` finishes the next line (and the next events in the chain) get executed.

Comment: E.g. if Button has 3 listeners and listener 2 has 10 lines. Line number 5 uses an `AndWait` method. all lines after line 5 won't execute and neither will listener 3. Once `AndWait` elapses the rest of the lines and listener 3 will get invoked

Answer (score -1):

Using `syncronized` will prevent concurrent execution of the method, but will essentially queue up the request that are made, by forcing threads to wait for any current execution.

When handling this scenario, you might want to debounce the button clicks, by preventing user interaction for some period after it is first pressed, or for the duration of the resulting computation, by disabling the button and re-enabling it

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however I downvoted it because it's a general answer that doesn't target Codename One and it can be confusing.